# Proving the possibility of rectangles within another

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

I was given this problem to prove yet Im having a hard time understanding what this problem actually is saying.

Here is what I am understanding:

In the plane we are given an infinite set of rectangles.

and every rectangle $(n_k,m_k)$ has the form where it must go through $(0,0)$ and the three other coordinates given above.

Now, how would I be able to prove that there exist two rectangles in the set such that one contains the other. The way I am visualizing is the rectangle (green) would only touch the origin but not the lengths of the bigger rectangle (red).

[image]

If possible can anyone give an example or an idea, it would help a lot.

Comment: Note that you must consider that a rectangle contain another one even if it touch the sides. Indeed, if we consider that in this case the rectangles are not contained in one another, the set of rectangles $\{ (1,n) | n\in \Bbb N^* \}$ would be an infinite set where there are no two rectangles that contains one another.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to notice that if there is no rectangles contained in one another, for each $m\in \Bbb N$, there is only one rectangle with height $m$. Indeed, if there was two, with with $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $n_1 < n_2$, the rectangle $(m,n_1)$ is contained in the rectangle $(m,n_2)$. By the same reasoning, each rectangle has a different width too.

Now, take the rectangle with the smallest height $m$, it has width $N$. But every other rectangle must have a width smaller that $N$, or else it would contain $(m,N)$. And as the rectangles have all a different width, there is at most $N$ rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R(n,m)$ be the rectangle whose upper right corner is at $\langle n,m\rangle$. If the set of rectangles were finite, it might, for instance, consist of the rectangles $R(1,6),R(2,5),R(3,4),R(4,3),R(5,2)$, and $R(6,1)$. If you sketch these, you’ll see that none of them is contained in any of the others. In fact, if you want $n$ rectangles, none of which contains any of the others, you can use

$$R(1,n),R(2,n-1),R(3,n-2),\ldots,R(n-1,2),R(n,1)\;,$$

the rectangles of the form $R(k,n+1-k)$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$. This shows that you’ll definitely need infinitely many rectangles in order to be sure that one of them is contained in another; your problem is to show that infinitely many is enough.

It’s easier to show the contrapositive:

> Let $\mathscr{R}$ be a family of rectangles of the form $R(n,m)$ such that no member of $\mathscr{R}$ contains any other member of $\mathscr{R}$; then $\mathscr{R}$ is finite.

HINT: Let $\mathscr{R}$ be as stated, and suppose that $\langle n,m\rangle\in\mathscr{R}$. Show that if $R(k,\ell)$ is any other member of $\mathscr{R}$, then either $k<n$ and $\ell>m$, or $k>n$ and $\ell<m$. (In other words, $\langle k,\ell\rangle$ is either above and to the left of $\langle n,m\rangle$, or below and to the right of $\langle n,m\rangle$.